# EJS Variable Throws Error Even Though It Renders Properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have an array of objects I am trying to iterate through in an ejs template, but I keep getting "Reference Error: bills is not defined".

Other StackOverflow questions said to test whether or not the variable was actually defined, so I used

```
<h1><%= bills.length %></h1>
```

This properly renders the length of the array, but it still throws an error at

```
ReferenceError: /index.ejs:11
    9|     <div id="billCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    10|       <!--Indicators-->
 >> 11|       <h1><%= bills.length %></h1>
```

If I replace this line with

```
<%= (typeof bills === 'undefined') ? "ERROR" : bills[0].TrackNum %>
```

Then the TrackNum of the first object is properly rendered, but the error moves to

```
ReferenceError: index.ejs:13
    11|       <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    12|         <%= (typeof bills === 'undefined') ? "ERROR" : bills[0].TrackNum %>
 >> 13|         <% for (var i=0; i < bills.length; i++) {%>
```

You can see all of the relevant code below.

pages/index.ejs

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <h1><%= (typeof bills == 'undefined') ? "ERROR" : bills[0].TrackNum %></h1>
    <% for (var i=0; i < bills.length; i++) {%>
      <li data-target="#billCarousel" data-slide-to="<%= i %>" class="<%= (i == 0) ? 'active':'' %>"></li>
    <% } %>
</ol>
```

server.js

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    billQuery.summary(function(data) {
        console.log(data.bills);
        response.render('pages/index', {
            page: "index",
            status: data.status,
            message: data.message,
            bills: data.bills
        });
    })
});
```

console.log(data.bills) properly prints the array to the console. I have tried rendering status and message in index.ejs, and they work fine. I have already set my Express Engine to EJS with

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

before I have the route to render index.ejs. I have also restarted my server and cleared my browser's cache several times, but the error keeps occurring. Is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because of a 404 error that resulted when the site tried to load the favicon.

```
app.get('*', function(request, response) {
    console.log("Couldn't retrieve "+request.url);
    response.render('pages/index', {
        page: "index",
        status: "Failed",
        message: "Error 404"
    });
});
```

When the server attempted to load favicon.ico, it called this route, which seems to delete the bills array which I passed in the "/" route. I put

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
```

in the head of index.ejs as a temporary fix. Once I changed this route to render a 404 page, the issue was permanently fixed.