# Node render json in ejs works, but throws sometimes errors

Tags: node.js, json, express, render, ejs

If path "/" gets called, i collect some data via RPC from a python process, which works really good. I want to use this JSON object to display some values in HTML (ejs). Actually it is working, but sometimes I get following error:

```
temperature is not defined
```

So what I have so far:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  client.invoke("data", function(error, data, more) {
    // console.log(data): {"temperature": "12", "minTemperature": "1", "maxTemperature": "101"}
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    // console.log(data): { temperature: '12', minTemperature: '1', maxTemperature: '101' }
    res.render('index', data);
  });
});
```

How I display the value in .ejs file:

```html
 <h4 id="temperature"><%- temperature %> °C</h4>
```

So with this JSON.parse I got it working. So the issue is now, in Chrome it is always throwing me this error. In Firefox it is working, but if I press CTRL+F5 it throws this error. (F5 only works). The funny part is, even if the error appears, the temperature gets displayed correctly. After burning some hours, I need your help...

Error:

```
temperature is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (/home/dominik/Schreibtisch/picam>/node/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:618:12), <anonymous>:37:17)
    at returnedFn (/home/dominik/Schreibtisch/picam/node/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:653:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/home/dominik/Schreibtisch/picam/node/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:251:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/dominik/Schreibtisch/picam/node/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:482:10)
    at View.render (/home/dominik/Schreibtisch/picam/node/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:76:8)
    at Function.app.render (/home/dominik/Schreibtisch/picam/node/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:561:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/home/dominik/Schreibtisch/picam/node/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:845:7)
    at /home/dominik/Schreibtisch/picam/node/server-tcp.js:50:7
    at callbacks (/home/dominik/Schreibtisch/picam/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
    at param (/home/dominik/Schreibtisch/picam/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
```

Comment: **Solution:** Issue was the favicon, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47385985/ejs-variable-throws-error-even-though-it-renders-properly

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to do `data.temperature` since you return `data` not `temperature`

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but I need to call data.temperature if I render it like that: res.render('index', {'data': data}); Same result, data gets displayed and works perfectly, but the error message is still there.